# How come it suffices to prove $P(X \geq a ) \leq \frac{E[X^2]}{a^2+ E[X^2]}$ for $E[X]=0$ to generalize it then for $E[Y] \geq 0 $ with $Y=X - E[X]$?

Tags: probability, inequality, logic, solution-verification

For some context about the inequality, it is in the proof of the Zygmund Paley inequality, I've posted another [question on the same proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506727/how-come-inf-exc%C2%B2-ac%C2%B2-c-geq-0-is-attained-at-c-sigma-%C2%B2)

> I have a problem about the proof that asks to show that :
>
> $$P(X \geq a ) \leq \frac{E[X^2]}{a^2+ E[X^2]}$$
>
> **assuming $E[X]=0$**.

Which is okay so far, as the proofs I've read use the argument,

Then it says, **let's assume now $E[X] \geq 0 $ only** by applying the last inequality to another well chosen variable, conclude that:

$$P(X \geq E[X] + a ) \leq \frac{VarX}{a^2+ VarX}$$

(which by my trials I found it has to be by substituting the variable X by $X-E[X]$ )

$$P(X - E[X] \geq  a ) \leq \frac{E[(X-E[X])^2]}{a^2+ E[(X-E[X])^2]}$$

which gives

$$P(X \geq E[X] + a ) \leq \frac{VarX}{a^2+ VarX}$$

My question here is more about the logic of this use in a proof, is it legitimate to generalize a result that was calculated for a variable whose expectation is null, but then generalized for a variable whose expectation again is not null,

by substituting $X$ with $E[X]+X$ , but if it is the case then we have to suppose the expectation of this new variable $E[X]+X$ to be null to be able to apply the result calculated for a variable whose expectation is null, that is $E[ E[X]+X ] =0$ , in which cases we get again $2E[X]=0$ so we have to suppose $E[X]=0$ and the generalization doesn't make sense for $E[X] \geq 0 $ only?

EDIT: I've made a mistake, the result is applied indeed to $E[X]-X$ and not $E[X]+X$, in this case should it make sense for $E[X] \geq 0 $ because we always have $E[ E[X]-X ] = 0 $?

Comment: By linearity of expectation, $E[X - E[X]] = E[X] - E[X] = 0$. So the substituted variable has expected value zero, and you already seem to know that the result holds for variables with zero expected value.

Comment: @Z.A.K. @ drhab yes my question is whether it makes sense to assume $E[X] \geq 0$ at the first place  because it will come back to $E[X] = 0 $

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake, it is $E[X²]$ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it be that $\mathbb EX\in[0,\infty)$ and define $Y:=X-\mathbb EX$.

Then evidently $\mathbb EY=0$ so that we can conclude that:$$P(Y \geq a ) \leq \frac{\mathbb E[Y^2]}{a^2+ \mathbb E[Y^2]}$$

Since $Y=X-\mathbb EX$ this can also be expressed as:$$P(X-\mathbb EX \geq a ) \leq \frac{\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb EX)^2]}{a^2+ \mathbb E[(X-\mathbb EX)^2]}$$
or as:$$P(X\geq\mathbb EX + a ) \leq \frac{\mathsf{Var}X}{a^2+ \mathsf{Var}X}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are not applying the first case to $X+EX$. You are applying it to $X-EX$ which has zero mean. Note that the event $X-EX \geq a$ is same as the event $X\geq EX+a$.

Comment: I do understand this, I wanted to know whether it makes sense to suppose $ E[X] \geq 0$ ?

Comment: No, it there is no reason to assume that $EX \geq 0$.  @Khan

Comment: That is what I thought too, but I have a problem that supposes that, so I supposed that there's a something wrong which I posted a question about here, maybe I am not seeing something.

Comment: Yes, it was  calculated for $ X-E[X]$ I've made a typing mistake thanks